# How to stringify a DOM node?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am creating a node:

```
var node = document.createElement("div");
node.setAttribute('class', 'my-class');
node.innerHTML = "Hello World";
```

Then I try to console.log the node in text format.
If I use `console.log(node)` I do not get string, but node (I need string!).
How can I get the whole node as string? Like this:

`<div class="my-class">Hello World</div>`

Comment: `console.log(node.outerHTML)`

Answer (score 3):

You can stringify a DOM node by using `node.outerHTML`.